# How to start activity in map view by default?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

i am developing android app to get direction between 2 location, as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW;
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=12.84281852,80.22529753&daddr=13.00355419,80.200881958"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Running this application, it is prompting me to choose one among 1) Browser 2) Map
How to open it in map by default in coding??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you call [`setPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29) with `'com.google.android.apps.maps'` it should launch Google maps.

---

This worked fine for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No problem. On Stackoverflow, we say thanks by accepting the answer (using the tick mark). That or upvotes. You're welcome.

Comment: Is it possible to start the intent in mapview or webview instead using startActivity. Because if again i use startActivity, the whole map is refreshed again. Is there any other way to use this without refreshing whole map???

Comment: You'll have to implement your own `MapView`. See [this tutorial](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/) for more details